# assigning unique keys to values and then merging files

Tags: r

I want to assign unique numerical keys to values(names) present in a file.
For example,
file name: abc and contents are

```
Nathaniel
John
Penny
Vicky
Sam
Sid
```

Then, a new file should be generated like,

```
V1  V2
0   Nathaniel
1   John
2   Penny
3   Vicky
4   Sam
5   Sid
```

How can i do it?
Also, then there is a file like,

```
V1           V2
Nathaniel    Penny
John         Sam
Penny       John
Vicky      Sid
Sam        John
```

Now, i have to convert it to a numerical file on the basis of the value assigned earlier.
Hence, the new file should be:

```
V1    V2
 0    2
 1    4
 2    1
 3    5
 4    1
```

How can i achieve it?
Please help.

Comment: Please post what you've got so far.

Comment: I have inserted a new column along with the contents of abc named file and the values in the new column has been filled by generated unique numbers. But I m having problems while merging. @wogsland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution without `merge`.In fact what you try to do here , is to "recode" variables in integers.On idea is to convert them to a `factor` then use `as.integer`.

First I read your first vector to use it as factor levels later :

```
## If you read values from a file
## change text= by file=
xx <- read.table(text='Nathaniel
John
           Penny
           Vicky
           Sam
           Sid')
```

Then I use this vector as levels factor.

```
## intermediate small function that transform character to integers
## Note I assume that xx$V1 don't have duplicate
to_integer <- function(x) as.integer(factor(x,levels=xx$V1,ord=TRUE))-1
## since we code the 2 vectors using same levels
transform(tab2, V3= to_integer(V1),V4=to_integer(V2))

#          V1    V2 V3 V4
# 1 Nathaniel Penny  0  2
# 2      John   Sam  1  4
# 3     Penny  John  2  1
# 4     Vicky   Sid  3  5
# 5       Sam  John  4  1
```

here I created `tab2` using :

```
tab2 <- read.table(text='V1           V2
Nathaniel    Penny
John         Sam
Penny       John
Vicky      Sid
Sam        John',header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Amazing answer thank you. However, I need files in the specified format only. @agstudy

Comment: File with numerical values. Please refer the example.

Comment: @ABC please try to understand the solution.

Comment: There aren't 5 or 6 values. There are more than 100 so, it isn't convenient to type all. @agstudy

Comment: @ABC you can read them from a file. I added a small comment to clarify how.